# check if setter is set PHP

Tags: php, oop, getter-setter

Hi is there a way to check if the setter in a class is set?

I've tried is_object and isset but without a proper result.

Example:

```
class FruitsModel{

    public $fruitId;

    public function setFruitId($fruitId){
        $this->fruitId = $fruitId;
    }

    public function displayFruit()
    {
        if(SETTER_FRUIT IS NOT SET){throw new Exception("FruitId is missing!");}

        echo $this->fruitId;

    }

}
```

Comment: [method_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)? But are you checking for the method, or for the property? [property_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php)?

Comment: A class that throws exceptions in unexpected situations: Good. A class method that `echo`'s instead of `return`'s => baaad. A class that throws, and uses setters should _not_ echo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A developer should know which methods need to be implemented in the class. Assuming that he does not, how could we force him to implement them without checking the existance of certain methods in your other methods programatically?

That's where interfaces come in handy and what they are for. See an interface as a contract that defines which methods a class **must** implement.

So the cleanest way to tackle your task would be to just implement an interface.

**FruitsModelInterface.php**

```
<?php

interface FruitsModelInterface{

    public function setFruitId($fruitId);

}
```

**FruitsModel.php**

```
<?php

class FruitsModel implements FruitsModelInterface{

    protected $fruitId;

    public function setFruitId($fruitId){
        $this->fruitId = $fruitId;
    }

    public function displayFruit()
    {
        if(is_null($this->fruitId))
            throw new FruitsModelException('Fruit ID missing!');
        echo $this->fruitId;
        // You'd probably better go with calling the Method
        // getFruit() though and return $this->fruitId instead of echoing
        // it. It's not the job ob the FruitsModel to output something
    }

}
```

Really, that's all the magic. Just force the FruitsModelInterface to implement the `setFruitId()` method by implementing the proper interface. In your `displayFruit()` you just check if the property really has been assigned.

I also made your property protected, so that you can be sure the value will just be set from within the class or it's children.

Happy Coding!

---

**Further reading**

- [PHP Docs - Interfaces](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.interfaces.php)

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is initalize $fruitId to null as default, then you can say: `if($this->fruitId === null){}`

By the way, make your attributes private, you don't want to have setters with a public variable :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `method_exits()`. Which check if a method exists within a class.

Something like:

```
$directory = new Directory('.');
var_dump(method_exists($directory,'read')); //method_exists return a bool
```

For more documentation check this link out: http://www.php.net/method_exists

Comment: method functions don't apply to variables

Comment: @mazzy: OP's wording _is_ confusing, and could be interpreted as asking _"How to check if a method was called"_

Comment: But you can check if the setter method exists, otherwise if you are checking if the property  has a value you can use a simple `if`

Comment: What he means with if the setter is set is if the variable has been assigned a value, not if the function exists

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make a function inside your class.

```
class FruitsModel {
    public function variableExists($key) {
        $retVal = false;
        if(isset($this->$key) == true) {
            $retVal = true;
        }

        return $retVal;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$fm = new FruidsModel();
echo $fm->variableExists($fruitId); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

creates a new method for the value of the variable, this can be private if you want another class does not have access to it:

```
class FruitsModel{

    public $fruitId = "";

    public function setFruitId($fruitId){
        $this->fruitId = $fruitId;
    }


   private function getFruitId(){

     return $this->$fruitId;

  }


    public function displayFruit()
    {
        if($this->getFruitId()  == ""){throw new Exception("FruitId is missing!");}

        echo $this->fruitId;

    }

}
```